# How a Combobox with the csOwnerDrawFixed Style can behave like the csDropDown style?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, ownerdrawn, tcombobox

I'm using a [TComboBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TComboBox) component with the style property set to *csOwnerDrawFixed*, I implement the *OnDrawItem* And everything works fine, Now I want which the combobox to behave like when had the *csDropDown* style (with the csOwnerDrawFixed style behaves like the csDropDownList style) , I mean with a inner editor. is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

Delphi's TComboBox wrapper doesn't support an owner draw editable style, but the underlying Windows control does, and it's easy to enable it.

Create a new descendant class like so:

```
TComboBox = class(StdCtrls.TComboBox)
public
  procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
end;

procedure TComboBox.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(OnDrawItem) then
    Params.Style := Params.Style or CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED
end;
```

Set the `Style` to `csDropDown` and assign `OnDrawItem` like you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

None of the OwnerDraw styles support the presence of an edit box in the `TComboBox`.  You will have to use a separate `TEdit` instead.